# What is `class A[_]` useful for?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

The types of symbols `class A[_]` or of `def a[_](x: Any)` have a type parameter that can't be referenced in the body, thus I don't see where it is useful for and why it compiles. If one tries to reference this type parameter, an error is thrown:

```
scala> class A[_] { type X = _ }
<console>:1: error: unbound wildcard type
       class A[_] { type X = _ }
                             ^

scala> def a[_](x: Any) { type X = _ }
<console>:1: error: unbound wildcard type
       def a[_](x: Any) { type X = _ }
                                   ^
```

Can someone tell me if such a type has a use case in Scala? To be exact, I do not mean existential types or higher kinded types in type parameters, only those litte `[_]` which form the complete type parameter list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because I did not get the answers I expected, I brought this to [scala-language](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-language/9oo9zXW5ew8).

I paste here the answer from Lars Hupel (so, all credits apply to him), which mostly explains what I wanted to know:

> I'm going to give it a stab here. I think the use of the feature gets
>   clear when talking about type members.
>
> Assume that you have to implement the following trait:
>
> ```
> trait Function {
>   type Out[In]
>   def apply[In](x: In): Out[In]
> }
> ```
>
> This would be a (generic) function where the return type depends on
>   the input type. One example for an instance:
>
> ```
> val someify = new Function {
>   type Out[In] = Option[In]   def
>   apply[In](x: In) = Some(x)
> }
>
> someify(3) res0: Some[Int] = Some(3)
> ```
>
> So far, so good. Now, how would you define a constant function?
>
> ```
> val const0 = new Function {
>   type Out[In] = Int
>   def apply[In](x: In) = 0
> }
>
> const0(3) res1: const0.Out[Int] = 0
> ```
>
> (The type `const0.Out[Int]` is equivalent to `Int`, but it isn't
>   printed that way.)
>
> Note how the type parameter `In` isn't actually used. So, here's how
>   you could write it with `_`:
>
> ```
> val const0 = new Function {
>   type Out[_] = Int
>   def apply[In](x: In) = 0
> }
> ```
>
> Think of `_` in that case as a name for the type parameter which
>   cannot actually be referred to. It's a for a function on the type
>   level which doesn't care about the parameter, just like on value
>   level:
>
> ```
> (_: Int) => 3 res4: Int => Int = <function1>
> ```
>
> Except …
>
> ```
> type Foo[_, _] = Int
> <console>:7: error: _ is already defined as type _
>        type Foo[_, _] = Int
> ```
>
> Compare that with:
>
> ```
> (_: Int, _: String) => 3 res6: (Int, String) => Int = <function2>
> ```
>
> So, in conclusion:
>
> ```
> type F[_] = ConstType // when you have to implement a type member def
> foo[_](...) // when you have to implement a generic method but don't
>             // actually refer to the type parameter (occurs very rarely)
> ```
>
> The main thing you mentioned, `class A[_]`, is completely symmetric to
>   that, except that there's no real use case.
>
> Consider this:
>
> ```
> trait FlyingDog[F[_]] { def swoosh[A, B](f: A => B, a: F[A]): F[B] }
> ```
>
> Now assume you want to make an instance of `FlyingDog` for your plain
>   old `class A`.
>
> ```
> new FlyingDog[A] { ... }
> // error: A takes no type parameters, expected: one
> // (aka 'kind mismatch')
> ```
>
> There are two solutions:
>
> 1. Declare `class A[_]` instead. (Don't do that.)
> 2. Use a type lambda:
>
>    ```
>    new FlyingDog[({ type λ[α] = A })#λ]
>    ```
>
> or even
>
> ```
> new FlyingDog[({ type λ[_] = A })#λ]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I had some casual ideas about what it could mean here:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5606

Besides the trivial use case, asking the compiler to make up a name because I really don't care (though maybe I'll name it later when I implement the class), this one still strikes me as useful:

> Another use case is where a type param is deprecated because
>   improvements in type inference make it superfluous.

```
trait T[@deprecated("I'm free","2.11") _, B <: S[_]]
```

> Then, hypothetically,
>   one could warn on usage of `T[X, Y]` but not `T[_, Y]`.

Though it's not obvious whether the annotation would come before (value parameter-style) or after (annotation on type style).

[Edit: "why it compiles": `case class Foo[_](i: Int)` still crashes nicely on 2.9.2]

Answer (score 2):

The underscore in Scala indicates an existential type, i.e. an unknown type parameter, which has two main usage:

- It is used for methods which do not care about the type parameter
- It is used for methods where you want to express that one type parameter is a type constructor.

A type constructor is basically something that needs a type parameter to construct a concrete type. For example you can take the following signature.

```
def strangeStuff[CC[_], B, A](b:B, f: B=>A): CC[A]
```

This is a function that for some `CC[_]` , for example a `List[_]`, creates a `List[A]` starting from a B and a function `B=>A`.

Why would that be useful? Well it turns out that if you use that mechanism together with implicits and typeclasses, you can get what is called ad-hoc polymorphism thanks to the compiler reasoning.

Imagine for example you have some higher-kinded type: `Container[_]` with a hierarchy of concrete implementations: `BeautifulContainer[_]`, `BigContainer[_]`, `SmallContainer[_]`. To build a container you need a

```
trait ContainerBuilder[A[_]<:Container[_],B] { 

def build(b:B):A[B]

}
```

So basically a ContainerBuilder is something that for a specific type of container A[_] can build an A[B] using a B.

While would that be useful ? Well you can imagine that you might have a function defined somewhere else like the following:

```
def myMethod(b:B)(implicit containerBuilder:ContainerBuilder[A[_],B]):A[B] = containerBuilder.build(b)
```

And then in your code you might do:

```
val b = new B()
val bigContainer:BigContainer[B] = myMethod(b)
val beautifulContainer:BeautifulContainer[B] = myMethod(b)
```

In fact, the compiler will use the required return type of myMethod to look for an implicit which satisfies the required type constraints and will throw a compile error if there is no ContainerBuilder which meets the required constraints available implicitely.

Comment: I didn't mean existential types or higher kinded types as type parameters, I meant a type parameter that exists but can't be referenced.

Comment: which previous one? The one that has been deleted?

Comment: The one by Stephane. The second example you gave is not legal. Why do you want a generic method without generic parameter?

Comment: I do not want it, I just wonder why it compiles when it does not make any sense.

Comment: `class A[_]` compiles `class A[_] { type X = _ }` does not. It is the former I wonder about because I can't see any use case for it (because the latter does not compile why wonderment gets even bigger).

Comment: you can't because _ it means unknown type. how you can assign something that is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

That's useful when you deal with instances of parametrized types without caring of the type parameter.

```
trait Something[A] {
  def stringify: String
}

class Foo extends Something[Bar] {
  def stringify = "hop"
}

object App {
  def useSomething(thing: Something[_]) :String = {
    thing.stringify
  }
}
```

Comment: What you mean here is an existential type, which is not what I meant.