# Is there special meaning to an underscore (_) in Type Bounds?

Tags: scala, types, existential-type, type-bounds

I'm trying to understand Scala's existential types.

Is there any difference between:

```
def foo[X <: Bar] = 3
```

and

```
def foo[_ <: Bar] = 3
```

or are they something more than just unnamed type parameters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is \`class A\[\_\]\` useful for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778963/what-is-class-a-useful-for)

Comment: By the way, let's not be confused. There is no existential here, only a (unnamed) type parameter.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Can you elaborate?

Comment: `List[_]` is an existential type, but `def foo[_]` just defines a generic method with an unnamed type parameter. Yes, both feature an underscore, but for two entirely different things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here `_` is indeed just an unnamed type parameter, no more, no less.
There is no difference between `def foo[_ <: Bar] = 3` and `def foo[X <: Bar] = 3` where `X` is unused.

**UPDATE**:

In response to: "I can't think of a use case for an unused type, I'd be grateful for one":

Note that this is pretty much the same as asking what is the purpose of having an argument if it is not used, such as in:

```
def foo( x: Int ) = 123
```

Usually a good reason for this is that the method conforms to a shape that is expected in some other API. 
By example, you want to pass the method (or rather its eta-expansio) to a another method that expects a parameter. By example:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(foo)
res0: List[Int] = List(123, 123, 123)
```

Another possibility is that your method is an override:

```
trait A {
  def foo( x: Int ): Int
}

trait B extends A {
  def foo( x: Int ) = 123
}
```

The same rational applies for type parameters. By example for the overriding case:

```
trait A {
  def foo[X <: Bar]: Int
}

trait B extends A {
  def foo[_<:Bar] = 3
}
```

`B.foo` does not need the type parameter in its implementation, but it has to be there (though unnamed) to conform to the method it is overriding.

Comment: Thanks - are there cases where it's something more than an anonymous type parameter, or is that a good intuitive explanation for what existential types are?

Comment: I would think that an anonymous type parameter is the same thing as an existential type. (Correct?)

Comment: I can't think of a use case for an unused type, I'd be grateful for one.