# Understanding of '_' (underscore) in Scala as a type variable

Tags: scala

In `Scala` I can use underscore as a type variable in function, for instance.

```
  def fun[_, _]() = {
    // ?
  }

  fun[Int, String]()
```

Is it so useful in real life programming? How could it be useful for me?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it so useful in real life programming?

No, it isn't.

> How could it be useful for me?

To confuse people. You *could* theoretically use it to mark an unused type parameter when e.g. overriding a method, but I don't think I've ever seen this.

Comment: I beg to differ. It has its uses. See this nearly identical question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202714/is-there-special-meaning-to-an-underscore-in-type-bounds

Comment: Hm. Ok, this falls under my last sentence. As I've said, I've never actually seen it used in this way :)